# Google visualisation - add Column and fill empty rows

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, googlevis

Hi here i have a google visualisation code:
http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/15/edit

First I create data (rows and column):

```
 data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
        ['Michael' , 'Male', 12, 5],
        ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
        ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
        ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
        ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
        ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
        ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8],
        ['Miranda', 'Female', 33, 6]
    ]);
```

Now I need to add new column to this so I write:

```
  data.addColumn('string', 'Kontrole');
```

So how I have new column and empty cells for that column so I need to fill them and I try this:

```
for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    if (data.getValue(y, 4) == '') {
        data.setValue(y, 4, '<i class="icon-pencil"></i>');
    }
}
```

but nothing happend, the cell are yet empty. Can someone see where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from new cells are `null` so you have to change

```
if (data.getValue(y, 4) == '') {
```

to

```
if (data.getValue(i, 4) == null) {
```